# Ruby FTP do not include Dir prefix

Tags: ruby, ftp

I'm attempting to grab some files via FTP, when changing the directory I am running into a prefix of my username which i believe is not needed. Here's my base code:

```
require 'net/ftp'

ftp = Net::FTP.new('example.com')
ftp.passive = false
ftp.debug_mode = true
ftp.login('A123456', 'password')
dir = ftp.chdir('THIS.IS.A.DIRECTORY.I.NEED')
files = ftp.list
ftp.close
```

files = ftp.list errors with: 550 No data sets found. When I know there are datasets using an FTP utility.

When i use ftp.pwd to see the working directory i see: 'A123456.THIS.IS.A.DIRECTORY.I.NEED'. I have researched how to remove the prefixed username to no avail. Any help on how to change the directory to simply : 'THIS.IS.A.DIRECTORY.I.NEED' would be great!

Comment: Are you passing a slash in front of your directory (since I assume you're passing the complete directory path)?

Comment: I am not passing any slash characters, what you see in `ftp.chdir('THIS.IS.A.DIRECTORY.I.NEED')` is exactly the same format as my real code. Should I be?

Comment: Depending on your FTP default home directory, it may be necessary. Can you try?

Comment: Does the `chdir` operation return success?

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata, where does the slash go exactly? `ftp.chdir('/THIS.IS.A.DIRECTORY.I.NEED')` does not work. @tadman, yes it returns success, i believe a 205 response.

Comment: **After** you login but **before** you change directories, make sure you run `ftp.list` and verify that `THIS.IS.A.DIRECTORY.I.NEED` is present in the list of remote directories. Also run `ftp.pwd` to see what your current directory name is. I suspect that you're trying to change into a directory that isn't there.